# Cookie not being saved when action ends with a round-trip to Challenge(AuthenticationProperties, string[])

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, authorization

We have a normal action method, in which we do the following:

```
CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    IsEssential = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = true,
    HttpOnly = false
};

HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("helpmework", "1", cookieOptions);

return Challenge(authenticationProps, scheme); // Request following this call does not contain above cookie
return Ok(); // next request successfully contains cookie
```

Basically if we end the method with a call to `Challenge`, parts of the code that continue running from the `Challenge`, don't end up having the added cookie. If we first add the cookie (in a separate request), and then try to do the above with `Challenge`, we can see the cookie just fine.

So the problem seems to be that if I add a cookie in the same request that I wish to authorize via `Challenge`, the cookie is still not saved in the `HttpContext` following the `Challenge` call, which was the reason I ended up using a cookie in the first place.

I think the cookie is not saved until the actual response is sent, which might explain why this happens. Any alternatives to the issue I'm experiencing?

Comment: Which kind of Authentication method are you using? Based on your code, I have checked it in my application (JWT authentication), after running the application, when access this action, it will return a 401 error page, use F12 developer tools to check the website cookie, I can find the cookie, the screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LmlO.png), please check it. Besides, you could also check whether you have enabled session in your application and enabled cookies in the browser. If still not working, try to post the related code in the configure service, it might help to fix it.

Comment: @ZhiLv I'm using OpenID connect middleware for the challenge. The SignInScheme is set to use IdentityServer4's cookie scheme, but I don't think that's related.